# How to select first 2 <li> elements using css

Tags: css

Hi i want to apply css for first 2 elements (one,two) that are adjacent to first `<p>` element.

```
<div class="one">
    <ul>
        <p>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
        <p>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Following getting applied to all 4 `li` elements

```
.one ul p:nth-child(odd) ~ li {
    background: lightsteelblue;
}
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid. You can't have a `<p>` tag as a direct descendant of `<ul>`.

Comment: Why not just define them with a class?

Comment: one & two only. sorry,updated the questions.  I have mark up like that in our application. how we can select elements 1st 2 li elements.

Comment: Why not change it? You are going to have problems with that invalid markup.

Comment: The problem with the invalid markup is that the browser will try to "fix" it when it builds the DOM so you'll end up something else than what the markup says, and it might be different in different browsers. For example Chrome renders that as `<ul><p></p><li>one</li><li>two</li><p></p>...` so you can't select the children of `<p>` since they end up *not* being the children of `<p>`.

Comment: Also bung your CSS + HTML through a checker. There are free ones on the web. Google it!

Answer (score 125):

For first 2 `li` elements inside `ul p` try:

```
.one ul li:nth-child(-n+3){
    // your style
}
```

See on [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/gShcy/)

And as other mates mentioned: you have invalid markup.

If you removed `p` element, try:

```
.one ul li:nth-child(-n+2){
    // your style
}
```

See on [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/gShcy/1/)

**Update:** My suggestion is to use another `ul` instead of `p`: So you have valid markup and same result:

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">
    <ul>
        <li>0</li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        <li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.one ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.one ul ul li:nth-child(-n+2){
    // your style
}
```

[**Updated jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/gShcy/2/)

**Note:** As your last comment, If you have only 2 special `li` element, Why not define a class name simply... `<li class="bold">`  **Do it simple**

```
ul li.bold {
    // your style
}
```

Comment: Thanks hallaji, this works. but how should i manage this if i don't know how many "li" elements exists adjacent to tag <p>

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean, one and two `li`s is inside `p` and not `adjacent`. If there was more than 2 `li` inside `p` tag, We have same effect again and only first 2 element will effect.

Comment: They are adjacent. My requirement is to apply css for all "li" elements that are adjacent to first <p> tag. I don't want to apply the css for li elements adjacent to 2nd <p>.

Answer (score 18):

This should be compatible with IE8 (uses CSS 2.1 selectors only):

```
li:first-child, li:first-child+li {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This has better compatibility with IE 7 & 8.  A little harder to read, but great if you need that market.

Answer (score 15):

First three elements you can select with e.g.

```
ul li:nth-of-type(-n+3) {

}
```

But like others mentioned, your markup is invalid and you should definitely correct it.

Answer (score 13):

Like others already mentioned, the straightforward answer would be `li:nth-child(-n+2) { ... }`.

I don't know about you, but when I first learn this `-n+2` part, my reaction was "what? is this a typo?". So, for those who like to know a little explanation rather than just copy-and-paste the counter-intuitive magic, here I include a link to a [wonderful blog post by Sara Cope](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) explaining the `-n+2` part:

> The syntax for selecting the first n number of elements is a bit counter-intuitive. You start with -n, plus the positive number of elements you want to select. For example, li:nth-child(-n+2) will select the first 2 li elements.

Such explanation is even missing in the [w3cshool for nth-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Comment: thanks for explaining & linking the nth-child formula