# Need to Capitalize first 2 words of Navigation bar

Tags: html, css, nav

I have a horizontal NAV section and need to capitalize the first 2 words (of 5). I need to capitalize the words Developers and Designers. I know its a class or span but I'm just learning CSS and can't figure it out.

thanks!

Here is the HTML

```
<header>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Developers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Designers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header nav ul li {
  float: right;
  width: 8%;
}

header nav a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 110px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select first 2 <li> elements using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672625/how-to-select-first-2-li-elements-using-css)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `text-transform: uppercase` and `nth-child` selector.

Something like this:

```css
header nav ul li:nth-child(-n+2) {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Developers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Designers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type).

For your example you will want to use `nth-of-type` on the `<li>`.

```
header nav li:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qfLrsdwr/1

My JSFiddle has slightly different selectors and markup for demonstration purposes.

```
<header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav class="primary-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Developers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Designers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

.primary-nav li {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
.primary-nav li:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone.  That did it!