# Underlining the first 5 elements in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginner webdeveloper. I use my project in Bootstrap 4.

I have menu with underline animation. It's work fine.

I have this code (menu and css):

```
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-family: "Now Medium";
        margin-top: 7px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 994px) {
        .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-family: "Now Medium";
            margin-top: 7px;
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    
        .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
            right: 0;
            width: 0;
            bottom: -5px;
            background: #0ad3f1;
            height: 2px;
            transition-property: width;
            transition-duration: 0.2s;
            transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        }
        .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover:after,
        .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus:after,
        .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:active:after {
            left: 0;
            right: auto;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg text-body px-md-0 pb-md-0 navbar-light w-100 pt-lg-0">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img src="images/logo.svg" class="brand-logo pb-2 pt-3 pt-md-0" title="logo">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu"
                        aria-controls="navbarmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="line"></span>
                    <span class="line"></span>
                    <span class="line"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarmenu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item d-block d-lg-none  d-xl-block text-center">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Start</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-center">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-center">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-center">
                            <a class="nav-link nav-link-selected" href="#">3 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-center">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item mx-xl-4 mb-2 mb-md-0 text-center">
                            <a class="nav-link order-visit" href="#">1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-center text-lg-right">
                            123
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item text-center d-inline-block d-lg-none language-box2">
                            abc
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

It's work fine, but I want underline animation for only first 4 elements in this menu.

I would like the current functionality to remain the same, but only for the first 4 items of my menu

How can I make it?

Please help me.

Comment: Still, do you need to emphasize the first 5 or 4 elements?

Comment: first 4 elements :)

Comment: you can use: nth-child (). which class or tag do you need to underline? navbar-nav li?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select first 2 <li> elements using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672625/how-to-select-first-2-li-elements-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified which selectors you want to emphasize, but I'm guessing it's `navbar-nav li`. I'll write you the rules for how to style the first 4 elements of many:

```
.navbar-nav li:nth-child(1),
.navbar-nav li:nth-child(2),
.navbar-nav li:nth-child(3),
.navbar-nav li:nth-child(4) {
   /*here you specify the styles you need for underlining*/
}
```

Comment: glad to help. if you have any questions, please contact us in the comments.